How to restrict access to any URL containing /admin/ in Spring Security?
I’m working with Spring Security, and I need to restrict access to any URL that contains /admin/ anywhere in the path. The goal is to ensure that only users with the SUPERVISOR role can access these URLs.
Here’s my current configuration:
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/authentication/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("**/admin/**").hasRole("SUPERVISOR")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAt(authenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
                        "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
                    ));
                    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
                    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
                    return configuration;
                })
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }
}

However, with this setup, I can still access paths containing /admin/ even without the SUPERVISOR role. How can I properly configure the security rules to ensure that /admin/ is restricted no matter where it appears in the URL?
I also tried using .pathMatchers("/**/admin/**").hasRole("SUPERVISOR"), but I encountered the following error:

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Invalid mapping pattern detected: //admin/
^
No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
Action:
Fix this pattern in your application or switch to the legacy parser implementation with 'spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher'.
Even after adding the spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher property to my application.yml, it still doesn’t work. It seems like this issue might be related to using Spring WebFlux instead of Spring MVC. What’s the best way to handle this in WebFlux?
